# how to store zero leading numbers in mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, casting

I want to store numbers like 09876 in mongoDb

I'm using php driver and so far I was casting my numbers to (int) , but I just noticed the numbers which starts with Zero , not saving in mongo properly and the zero drops !

So my numbers in mongo are like : **NumberLong(9876)**   but it must be :  **NumberLong(09876)**

So I know I can cast my numbers to String and save them exactly as they are , but is there a way beside this  ?

I mean , I dont want to store numbers as Strings in mongo db

something like casting to char ???

Comment: "09876" is not a number. You have to store it as a string. Or, store a normal number 9876 and format with leading zeros when you read and output it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers are stored as values and any leading zeroes will ALWAYS be dropped in numeric fields. You have 2 options:

1. Store it as text.
2. Format it before displaying to add the zeroes.

Comment: OK 
I prefer to go with 2
but I dont know what numbers has been dropped! 
I mean not all of my nubers start with Zero

Comment: You do know how many digits your number is supposed to have, right? Check if it is missing any and then add the missing digits as zeroes.